# No texture when importing FBX into Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, textures, fbx

I am having problems importing an FBX file into Unity.

I downloaded a zip file that contains the following files: 3DS, DAE, FBX, MTL, OBJ, TGA, and several PNG files.  The model contains no animations.

I have tried dozens of ways to import the model (3DS, FBX, DAE...), but I mostly just get the basic model with no texture (white on all sides).  One of the PNG files appears to be the image which should be overlaid on the model.  When I drag the PNG file on top of the model in my scene, it is rotated 180 degrees from what it should be.  I have tried numerous combinations of rotating the model, but always get the same result (180 degrees off).  Can someone explain how to make the PNG file lay correctly on the model?

Also, please tell me if I am correctly importing the FBX file.  Import New Asset.. is simple, but from there I seem to get lost.  Should I need to drag an image on top of the model post-import?  Note that upon importing, the Inspector states that materials are embedded inside the asset.  To me, this implies that the model has everything it needs, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I'm quite not sure what your doing but you typically pull in the PNG files which are your Albedo, Normal Map, Occlusion Map, Metallic Map and whatever else, create a material for it, assign the images (PNG) appropriately to the material and the model takes a material.  PNG's don't get directly applied to a Mesh.